# Neo4j: Cypher query how to match result with value only contains in array

Tags: neo4j

I have a neo4j with label (A)-[:REL]->(B), I want to select node A that have :REL with B where B.id only in input array(B.id dont have diff value with input)
Example:

```
A1 :REL B1: {id:[1,2,3]}
A2 :REL B2: {id:[1,3]}
A3 :REL B3: {id:[3]}
```

with input array [1,3]

return A2 & A3, because A1 have :REL with B id=2 not in input array

I have tried this but not correct, still return A1

```
where apoc.coll.contains([1,3],b.id)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I found it:

```
match(A)-[:REL]->(B)
with A,collect(B.id) as ids
WHERE NOT ANY (x IN ids WHERE NOT x IN {inputArray})
```

Thanks all